# C# class to dump the memory of a process in several formats

Tags: c#, .net, pointers, windows, memory-optimization

I made this because I couldn't find any good C# classes/libraries that allow you to dump the contents of a process' memory into a file or a byte array. I haven't tested this on 32 bit systems but it works in both x86 and x64 on my 64 bit system. I've been mostly testing this on the notepad process which executes pretty quickly, but I've also tried this on the steam process with 120 mb memory which worked but took around 30 seconds. How can I improve this and what bugs have I overlooked? Any feedback is appreciated,  thanks.

MemoryDump.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;

namespace MemoryDumper
{
    public struct Chunk
    {
        public Dumper.MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION MemoryInformation;
        public byte[] Bytes;
    }

    public class MemoryDump
    {
        public MemoryDump(Chunk[] chunks)
        {
            Chunks = chunks;

            long bytesSum = 0;
            foreach (var chunk in chunks)
                bytesSum += chunk.Bytes.Length;

            Bytes = new byte[bytesSum];

            int byteOffset = 0;
            foreach (var chunk in chunks)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < chunk.Bytes.Length; i++)
                {
                    Bytes[byteOffset + i] = chunk.Bytes[i];
                }
                byteOffset += chunk.Bytes.Length;
            }
        }

        public readonly Chunk[] Chunks;
        public readonly byte[] Bytes;

        public string BytesString
        {
            get
            {
                byte[] cleansedBytes = Bytes;
                for (int i = 0; i < Bytes.Length; i++)
                    cleansedBytes[i] = (byte)ToChar(cleansedBytes[i]);

                return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(cleansedBytes);
            }
        }

        public static char ToChar(byte bt)
        {
            bool isPrintable = bt >= 32 && bt <= 126;
            return isPrintable ? (char)bt : '.';
        }

        [Flags]
        public enum DumpSaveOptions
        {
            // ex: 43 6F 77 4E 61 74 69 6F 6E
            BytesArray = 1,
            // ex: CowNation
            BytesString = 2,
            // ex: 43 6F 77 4E 61 74 69 6F 6E | CowNation
            Both = BytesArray | BytesString
        };

        public void Save(string filePath, DumpSaveOptions options = DumpSaveOptions.Both, int bytesPerLine = 56)
        {
            if (!File.Exists(filePath))
                throw new Exception("File '" + filePath + "' doesn't exist");

            bool bytesArray = (options & DumpSaveOptions.BytesArray) != 0;
            bool bytesString = (options & DumpSaveOptions.BytesString) != 0;

            StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(filePath);
            for (int i = 0; i < Bytes.Length / bytesPerLine; i++)
            {
                // the bytes for this line
                byte[] lineBytes = new byte[bytesPerLine];
                Array.Copy(Bytes, i * bytesPerLine, lineBytes, 0, bytesPerLine);

                string line = "";
                string dataString = "";
                foreach (byte bt in lineBytes)
                {
                    if (bytesArray)
                    {
                        string b = bt.ToString("X");
                        line += (b.Length == 1 ? "0" + b : b) + " ";
                    }

                    if (bytesString)
                        dataString += ToChar(bt);
                }
                line += (bytesArray && bytesString ? "| " : "") + dataString;

                streamWriter.WriteLine(line);
            }

            streamWriter.Close();
        }
    }

    public class Dumper
    {
        #region IMPORTS
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        static extern IntPtr OpenProcess(ProcessAccessFlags dwDesiredAccess, bool bInheritHandle, int dwProcessId);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern bool ReadProcessMemory(
           IntPtr hProcess,
           IntPtr lpBaseAddress,
           byte[] lpBuffer,
           int nSize,
           out IntPtr lpNumberOfBytesRead);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        static extern void GetSystemInfo(out SYSTEM_INFO lpSystemInfo);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern int VirtualQueryEx(IntPtr hProcess, IntPtr lpAddress, out MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION lpBuffer, uint dwLength);
        #endregion

        #region ENUMS
        public enum AllocationProtectEnum : uint
        {
            PAGE_EXECUTE = 0x00000010,
            PAGE_EXECUTE_READ = 0x00000020,
            PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE = 0x00000040,
            PAGE_EXECUTE_WRITECOPY = 0x00000080,
            PAGE_NOACCESS = 0x00000001,
            PAGE_READONLY = 0x00000002,
            PAGE_READWRITE = 0x00000004,
            PAGE_WRITECOPY = 0x00000008,
            PAGE_GUARD = 0x00000100,
            PAGE_NOCACHE = 0x00000200,
            PAGE_WRITECOMBINE = 0x00000400
        }

        public enum StateEnum : uint
        {
            MEM_COMMIT = 0x1000,
            MEM_FREE = 0x10000,
            MEM_RESERVE = 0x2000
        }

        public enum TypeEnum : uint
        {
            MEM_IMAGE = 0x1000000,
            MEM_MAPPED = 0x40000,
            MEM_PRIVATE = 0x20000
        }

        [Flags]
        enum ProcessAccessFlags : uint
        {
            All = 0x001F0FFF,
            Terminate = 0x00000001,
            CreateThread = 0x00000002,
            VirtualMemoryOperation = 0x00000008,
            VirtualMemoryRead = 0x00000010,
            VirtualMemoryWrite = 0x00000020,
            DuplicateHandle = 0x00000040,
            CreateProcess = 0x000000080,
            SetQuota = 0x00000100,
            SetInformation = 0x00000200,
            QueryInformation = 0x00000400,
            QueryLimitedInformation = 0x00001000,
            Synchronize = 0x00100000
        }
        #endregion

        #region STRUCTS
        public struct MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION
        {
            public IntPtr BaseAddress;
            public IntPtr AllocationBase;
            public AllocationProtectEnum AllocationProtect;
            public IntPtr RegionSize;
            public StateEnum State;
            public AllocationProtectEnum Protect;
            public TypeEnum Type;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct SYSTEM_INFO
        {
            public ushort processorArchitecture;
            ushort reserved;
            public uint pageSize;
            public IntPtr minimumApplicationAddress;
            public IntPtr maximumApplicationAddress;
            public IntPtr activeProcessorMask;
            public uint numberOfProcessors;
            public uint processorType;
            public uint allocationGranularity;
            public ushort processorLevel;
            public ushort processorRevision;
        }
        #endregion

        public static MemoryDump Dump(Process process)
        {
            if (process == Process.GetCurrentProcess()) // a recursive memory allocation loop happens in this case until it runs out of memory
                throw new Exception("Cannot dump the memory of this process");

            List<Chunk> chunks = new List<Chunk>();

            SYSTEM_INFO systemInfo = new SYSTEM_INFO();
            GetSystemInfo(out systemInfo);

            IntPtr minimumAddress = systemInfo.minimumApplicationAddress;
            IntPtr maximumAddress = systemInfo.maximumApplicationAddress;

            IntPtr processHandle = OpenProcess(ProcessAccessFlags.QueryInformation | ProcessAccessFlags.VirtualMemoryRead, false, process.Id);
            if (processHandle == IntPtr.Zero)
                throw new Exception("Cannot get a handle to process");

            while (minimumAddress.ToInt64() < maximumAddress.ToInt64())
            {
                MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION memoryInformation = new MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION();
                VirtualQueryEx(processHandle, minimumAddress, out memoryInformation, (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION)));

                // check if this chunk is accessible
                if (memoryInformation.Protect == AllocationProtectEnum.PAGE_READWRITE && memoryInformation.State == StateEnum.MEM_COMMIT)
                {
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[memoryInformation.RegionSize.ToInt64()];
                    ReadProcessMemory(processHandle, memoryInformation.BaseAddress, buffer, memoryInformation.RegionSize.ToInt32(), out IntPtr bytesRead);

                    chunks.Add(new Chunk
                    {
                        MemoryInformation = memoryInformation,
                        Bytes = buffer
                    });
                }

                // move to the next chunk
                try
                {
                    minimumAddress = new IntPtr(minimumAddress.ToInt64() + memoryInformation.RegionSize.ToInt64());
                }
                catch (OverflowException)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }

            return new MemoryDump(chunks.ToArray());
        }
    }
}
```

Example Usage:

```
    var dump = Dumper.Dump(Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad")[0]);
    dump.Save("dump.txt");
    File.WriteAllText("bytesString.txt", dump.BytesString);
```

Comment: I tried it and I have to cast all ToInt64() to ulong (like (ulong)maximumAddress.ToInt64()), otherwise I end up with negative values. Other than that it worked, but the text I typed into Notepad doesn't show up in your dump.

Comment: Is the question still valid? Still need advice?